# npm throws an error everytime I try to install anything

Tags: npm, npm-install

Every time I try to install vue.js or bulma, npm throws an error. Please help.

```
Error:"
└── bulma@0.4.1 

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/thabiso/package.json'
npm WARN thabiso No description
npm WARN thabiso No repository field.
npm WARN thabiso No README data
npm WARN thabiso No license field.
"
```

I'm not really sure what the above error means, but npm won't work. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling npm but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Either create the package.json file first, or simple run `npm init` to have npm take care of it for you.